# No more notification for iMessage with Mavericks

Tags: macos, messages, notifications

I did the upgrade to Mavericks few days ago. I noticed a problem with my iMessage app : I don't get any notification when I received a new message (neither alert, nor badges on the icon in the Dock).

How can I troubleshoot if this is a problem with my computer or account or perhaps my network connection?

Comment: Have you tried logging out off iMessage and logging back in?

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences > Notifications.

1. Make sure that you're not in the 'Do not disturb" mode.
2. Check your settings for the Messages app. Enable 'Banners' if they're off (or even 'Alerts').

Comment: Sorry for delay ; it seems it was a Mavericks-linked problem : upgrading solved that.
Thanks for helping ;)